# How to find the maximum number in while loop

Tags: python

I have written a program to produce the sum and the max number as long as I input, and break when I input 0. I can find the sum now, but the program cannot give me the max....It just gives me 0. Why? and how to solve it?

```
sumN = 0
maxN = 0
while True:
    n=int(input())    
    if n == 0:
        break
    else:
        sumN += n 
    if n > maxN:
        maxN == n
print(sumN)
print(maxN)
```

For example, when I input 3 3 3, the sumN gives me 9, but maxN only gives me 0. What's wrong with my code??
Thanks!!

Comment: maybe `maxN = n` ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You are using comparing instead of assignment

```
if n > maxN:
    maxN = n
```

Answer (score 0):

What @CONvid19 is saying is that

```
maxN == n
```

is a test for equality. What you want is :

```
maxN = n
```

which is an assignment.